# Убрать кнопку (вертикальных три точки) из ActionBar

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Когда я создаю Toolbar в layout-е, появляются кнопка(вертикальные три точки). Как это убрать, при этом меню должно остатся ?

XML:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
         <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
              android:id="@+id/toolbar"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
              android:background="#FFFFFF"
              app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
         </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header_menu"
        app:menu="@menu/main_menu" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

кнопка добавляется в том случае когда я выполняю

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Также в Action bar должна быть кнопка home. Отображаю её так:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

### Скрин с кнопкой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текст menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_home"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
            android:title="@string/menu_home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_catalog"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_list"
            android:title="@string/menu_goods_catalog" />
    </group>
    <group android:id="@+id/second" android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_login"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_account"
            android:title="@string/menu_login" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_account"
            android:title="@string/menu_profile" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_history_order"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_order"
            android:title="@string/menu_history_order" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_favorite"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_fav"
        android:title="@string/menu_favorite"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_counter" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_history"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_history"
        android:title="@string/menu_history" />
</group>
<group android:id="@+id/third" android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_info"
        android:title="@string/menu_info" />
</group>
```

Comment: странный вопрос, но меню вы хотите оставить? просто от этого зависит решение проблемы)

Comment: Да, хочу оставить

Comment: Тогда вопрос в корне меняется, добавьте пожалуйста это важное замечание в вопрос, потому что вот люди внизу, уже не корректно отвечают.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` реагирует, на контейнер меню по стандарту `.xml` в папке меню, и эта икона своего рода отображения этого контейнера только уже визуально. Если у Вас контейнер не пустой, тогда появляется эта иконка, в противном случае её нет. Если иконка у вас одна и вы просто хотите заменить эти три точки то в menu.xml указываем: `showAsAction="always"` и иконка сменится, но если у вас много пунктов и вы не хотите её видеть придется использовать фичу. Смысл заключается в том, чтоб сделать эти иконки невидимыми или недоступными(работают оба способа), тогда виджет будет думать, что их нет и скроет отображение "трех точек".

К примеру у вас есть такое меню:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Переопределяем метод `onPrepareOptionsMenu`

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu){

menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(false);

return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Если итемов несколько, делаем всё аналогично. Эту же фичу можно использовать, для того чтоб показать нужную иконку - тогда `.xml` меню, выбираем нужный `item` и устанавливаем показывать `showAsAction="always"` остальные скрываем.

Пример для вашей разметки:

### menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<group android:id="@+id/first" android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:title="@string/menu_home" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_catalog"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_list"
        android:title="@string/menu_goods_catalog" />
</group>
<group android:id="@+id/second" android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_login"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_account"
        android:title="@string/menu_login" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_account"
        android:title="@string/menu_profile" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_history_order"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_order"
        android:title="@string/menu_history_order" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_favorite"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_fav"
    android:title="@string/menu_favorite"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_counter" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_history"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_history"
    android:title="@string/menu_history" />
</group>
<group android:id="@+id/third" android:checkableBehavior="single">
<item
    android:id="@+id/info"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_info"
    android:title="@string/menu_info" />
</group>
```

### onPrepareOptionsMenu в Activity.class

```
    @Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.setGroupVisible(R.id.first, false);
    menu.setGroupVisible(R.id.second, false);
    menu.setGroupVisible(R.id.third, false);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: Добавил в меню action_settings и переопределил onPrepareOptionsMenu(), не помогло(

Comment: значит ошибка в другом, покажите код menu.xml

Comment: отредактировал вопрос, в вопросе добавил код menu.xml

Comment: какая мощная менюшка) я сейчас добавлю в ответ, постараюсь минимум затронуть элементы, добавлю одну группу и назову first.

Comment: мощная в плохом или хорошем смысле ?)

Comment: давно не видел менюшки, мне кажется люди не хотят их использовать. В хорошем смысле.

Comment: =) Попробую применить ваш код послезавтра, когда выйду на работу) в любом случае ставлю плюс, спасибо за потраченное время.

Comment: Большое спасибо, ваш вариант решил мою проблему)

Answer (score 0):

Удали подобное из MainActivity

```
Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Не подходит, у меня в ActionBar отбражается кнопка домой, если я уберу код который вы написали, то естественно нажатие на кнопку home работать не будет.