# Отображение меню в OptionMenu в трёх точках на девайсе с хардверной кнопкой меню

Tags: java, android, android-menu

Смартфон на android 4.2.2

Хочу сделать меню чтоб была кнопка "Добавить", в виде иконки с изображением.

*код xml:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".CrimeListActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_new_crime"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
        android:title="@string/new_crime"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        />
        <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_option"
        android:title="@string/option"
        />
</menu>
```

Добавляю его в фрагмент через метод

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_crime_list, menu);
    }
```

Потом

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

**Проблема в том, что меню отображается только когда нажимаю кнопку опций на самом смартфоне!**

**в чем может быть проблема? И как ее решить ?**

Comment: `myToolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.my_menu)` попробуйте

Comment: @Abrog Petrovich, где это прописывать ?

Comment: в onCreate (или в какой момент меню создается?) после инициализации myToolbar

Comment: @Abrog Petrovich, я представление для меню задаю в методе onCreateOptionsMenu

Comment: для Toolbar лучше создавать в onCreate (если нет никаких обязательных причин вызывать onCreateOptionsMenu) - работает точно так же

Comment: @Abrog Petrovich, понимаете, оно работает  при нажатии кнопки "Опции" на самом смартфоне (то есть оно работает ), на эмуляторе отображается 3 точки (типа меню). НО мне нужно чтоб отображалось та пикча которою я задал и на эмуляторе, и на смартфоне (НЕ НАЖИМАЯ кнопку опций). Меня интересует - КАК это сделать ?

Comment: setSupportActionBar(myToolbar) попробуйте (в onCreate)

Comment: @Abrog Petrovich, я не создаю тулбар !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Мне нужно через optionmenu фрагмента задать меню !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто укажите всегда отображаться в `ActionBar/Toolbar` и не прятаться в "три точки" через аттрибут `app:showAsAction` со значением `always` Т.е. замените нынешние `ifRoom|withText` на

```
app:showAsAction="always"
```

**UPD_0:**

1. Попробуйте также подключить библиотеку поддержки и унаследовать активити и фрагменты от классов из библиотеки поддержки.
2. onCreateOptionsMenu методе фрагмента надо бы код писать до вызова `super` и там, вроде, надо не инфлейтить меню новое, а добавлять программно новые пункты в готовое. Типа `menu.add(...)`.
3. Отсутствие иконок же в меню - бага, которая лечится добавлением вот этого кода в активити:

   ```
   //workaround from https://stackoverflow.com/a/30337653/3212712 to show menu icons
   @Override
   protected boolean onPrepareOptionsPanel(View view, Menu menu)
   {
       if (menu != null)
       {
           if (menu.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("MenuBuilder"))
           {
               try
               {
                   Method m = menu.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setOptionalIconsVisible", Boolean.TYPE);
                   m.setAccessible(true);
                   m.invoke(menu, true);
               }
               catch (Exception e)
               {
                   Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "onMenuOpened...unable to set icons for overflow menu", e);
               }
           }
       }
       return super.onPrepareOptionsPanel(view, menu);
   }
   ```

**UPD_1:**

Согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11438245/3212712), чтобы отобразить `overflow` меню на девайсах с хардверной кнопкой меню нужно использовать грязный хак, т.к. это не соответствует видению гугла сего нюанса:
добавьте ещё вот это в `onCreate` класса `Application`.

```
try {
        ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
        Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
        if(menuKeyField != null) {
            menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
            menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // Ignore
    }
```

Этот код жёстко задаст отображение меню в "трёх точках" на девайсах с хардверной кнопкой меню.

Comment: У меня не отображает ни три точки, ни изображения иконки А нужно , чтоб один пункт отображало в виде иконки, а в торой в меню с тремя точками.

Comment: @Vitaliy, см. обновлённый ответ.

Comment: сделал ! точек все равно нет !

Answer (score 1):

Я отвечал на данный вопрос, очень подробно.

Если вам интересны детали, тогда можете глянуть сюда: [Три точки Menu, почему?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/491979/%D0%A3%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-actionbar/491995#491995)

Comment: Спасибо за отклик, но у меня проблема иная (просто заголовок моего вопроса не правильно отредактировали).

Мне нужно чтобы три точки меню отображались в actionBar, а их почему-то нет, чтобы я не делал.  И как можно увидеть в коде, что я написал в вопросе - один пункт меню имеет иконку, но она тоже не отображается!!!! 

В чием может быть проблема ? Я подозреваю, что это из за того, что на моем смартфоне есть физическая кнопка опций и я не знаю как ее можно проигнорировать !!

Comment: нет не в этом проблема -точно. Так как я работаю с такими устройствами, я бы заметил бы такое поведение. Попробую подробней изучить проблему. Напишите версию API и ваше устройство мне очень интересно

Comment: API 17, Lenovo A850. 

Может быть данная проблема из за того, что я не использую супорт библиотеку ?

Comment: Я проверил, всё отлично работает. с API14+ и на API 17. Могу дать набросок кода, где происходит инициализация вашего меню через фрагмент, никаких проблем. Значит ошибка в другом месте вашего кода, иначе быть не может

Comment: буду очень благодарен! 
Если не можно то архивом в ЛС вконтакте 
https://vk.com/id103711159 , или здесь ответом